# Laptop randomly shutting down / suspending after a few minutes. 20.04.2 LTS

Tags: 20.04, suspend, shutdown, udev

I turn the latop on, I log in, then after 1-2 minutes the laptop shuts down.
Just before it turns off completely, it goes to the lock screen.

This has started today - and I don't think I installed any updates in the last few days.

**EDIT 2**

Following waltinator advice I checked the `journalctl` output and discovered that something is triggering the power switch. Then after a bit of digging I found this question - https://superuser.com/questions/1071800/explanation-of-systemd-logind-in-auth-log

The output from `udevadm trigger` is below. So my questions now are - Why are the webcam, microphone, hdmi output etc. communicating with the power switch; is this causing the random power off; and if so how do I disable these messages?

```
$ udevadm trigger -v -n -g power-switch
/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXPWRBN:00/input/input3/event3
/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0A08:00/LNXVIDEO:00/input/input21/event9
/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0C:00/input/input0/event0
/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0D:00/input/input2/event2
/sys/devices/LNXSYSTM:00/LNXSYBUS:00/PNP0C0E:00/input/input1/event1
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-8/1-8:1.0/input/input30/event18
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input22/event10
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input23/event11
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input24/event12
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input25/event13
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input26/event14
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input27/event15
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input28/event16
/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.3/sound/card0/input29/event17
/sys/devices/platform/INT33D5:00/input/input17/event8
/sys/devices/platform/i8042/serio0/input/input4/event4

$ udevadm trigger -v -n -g power-switch | xargs -i cat {}/../name
Power Button
Video Bus
Power Button
Lid Switch
Sleep Button
BisonCam,NB Pro: BisonCam,NB Pr
HDA Intel PCH Rear Mic
HDA Intel PCH Front Mic
HDA Intel PCH Headphone
HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=3
HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=7
HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=8
HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=9
HDA Intel PCH HDMI/DP,pcm=10
Intel HID events
AT Translated Set 2 keyboard
```

---

This is output from `kern.log` for the last 5 shutdowns.

```
May 26 17:23:52 jamest-Hybris kernel: [   17.087827] mce: CPU2: Package temperature/speed normal
May 26 17:23:52 jamest-Hybris kernel: [   17.087828] mce: CPU6: Package temperature/speed normal
May 26 17:23:52 jamest-Hybris kernel: [   17.193695] rfkill: input handler disabled
May 26 17:25:21 jamest-Hybris kernel: [  106.238840] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 44:e9:dd:0c:a0:07 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
May 26 17:25:23 jamest-Hybris kernel: [  108.184069] PM: suspend entry (deep)
...
May 26 17:29:01 jamest-Hybris kernel: [   16.522151] rfkill: input handler enabled
May 26 17:29:03 jamest-Hybris kernel: [   18.299032] FAT-fs (sdb1): Volume was not properly unmounted. Some data may be corrupt. Please run fsck.
May 26 17:29:03 jamest-Hybris kernel: [   18.385620] rfkill: input handler disabled
May 26 17:30:28 jamest-Hybris kernel: [  103.505036] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 44:e9:dd:0c:a0:07 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
May 26 17:30:30 jamest-Hybris kernel: [  105.493465] PM: suspend entry (deep)
...
May 26 17:32:32 jamest-Hybris kernel: [   41.950990] mce: CPU7: Package temperature/speed normal
May 26 17:32:32 jamest-Hybris kernel: [   41.950990] mce: CPU4: Package temperature/speed normal
May 26 17:32:32 jamest-Hybris kernel: [   41.950991] mce: CPU0: Package temperature/speed normal
May 26 17:33:35 jamest-Hybris kernel: [  104.349444] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 44:e9:dd:0c:a0:07 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
May 26 17:33:39 jamest-Hybris kernel: [  109.180738] PM: suspend entry (deep)
...
May 26 17:35:47 jamest-Hybris kernel: [   15.053073] rfkill: input handler enabled
May 26 17:35:48 jamest-Hybris kernel: [   15.404181] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlp2s0: link becomes ready
May 26 17:35:49 jamest-Hybris kernel: [   16.834008] rfkill: input handler disabled
May 26 17:37:16 jamest-Hybris kernel: [  103.671054] wlp2s0: deauthenticating from 44:e9:dd:0c:a0:07 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
May 26 17:37:20 jamest-Hybris kernel: [  108.026954] PM: suspend entry (deep)
```

I haven't (knowingly) done anything to trigger the suspend.

Some system information

sudo lshw -C video

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:137 memory:a0000000-a0ffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

lspci

```
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 8th Gen Core 4-core Processor Host Bridge/DRAM Registers [Coffee Lake H] (rev 07)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation UHD Graphics 630 (Mobile)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Thermal Subsystem (rev 07)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Thermal Controller (rev 10)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH USB 3.1 xHCI Host Controller (rev 10)
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Shared SRAM (rev 10)
00:15.0 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #0 (rev 10)
00:15.1 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH Serial IO I2C Controller #1 (rev 10)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH HECI Controller (rev 10)
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake Mobile PCH SATA AHCI Controller (rev 10)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #9 (rev f0)
00:1d.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #14 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH PCI Express Root Port #15 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation HM470 Chipset LPC/eSPI Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH cAVS (rev 10)
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SMBus Controller (rev 10)
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Cannon Lake PCH SPI Controller (rev 10)
02:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9260 (rev 29)
03:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
03:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
```

**EDIT**

Following waltinator's reply here is the relevant part of journalctl. It looks like the system thinks the power button is being pressed and then shutting down 4-5 seconds later. I'm definitely not pressing the button so it looks like it might a hardware problem.

```
May 26 17:37:15 machine-abc systemd-logind[968]: Power key pressed.
May 26 17:37:15 machine-abc gnome-shell[1876]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 38 with keysym 38 (keycode 11).
...
...
...
May 26 17:37:20 machine-abc systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
May 26 17:37:20 machine-abc systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
May 26 17:37:20 machine-abc systemd-sleep[3054]: Suspending system...
May 26 17:37:20 machine-abc kernel: PM: suspend entry (deep)
```

Answer (score 1):

After a "sudden shutdown", aka "system crash", and reboot, the terminal  command `sudo journalctl  -b -1 -e` will show you the end of the previous boot's log's. If there is no hint there, suspect power/ overheating.

Read `man journalctl` to see how to extract information from the logs.

You can find how I make use of `journalctl` easier at `https://askubuntu.com/users/25618/waltinator`.

Comment: Added in an edit to my question. It looks like the system thinks the power button is being pressed and then shutting down 4-5 seconds later. I'm definitely not pressing the button so it looks like it might a hardware problem.