# Ubuntu Shuts down After 2 Minutes / Beeping & Freezing in Recovery mode

Tags: boot, 22.04, shutdown

I upgraded from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 and two days later (without any new installations since then, but possibly also without any rebooting) my laptop keeps shutting down after 2 minutes, independent of what i did in those 2 minutes.

As a brief "warning" the normal popup window with the message "Power Off - The system will power off automatically in 60 seconds" appears, but the system shuts down 5 seconds later.

Trying to start in recovery mode, the laptop starts beeping continously, and the terminal freezes after ~15 seconds.

What I tried so far: Upon starting, there were error messages related to sssd, but disabeling sssd didn't help. (The messages disappeared, but the systrm keeps shutting down.)

/var/log/kern.log showed a lot of messages related to snapd-desktop-integration, but removing it also didn't help with the problem.

I don't know if the fans are still working, they don't seem to turn on. Installing fancontrol and using pwmcontrol didnt work, as there are no sensors found. But i am not sure how to even test, if this is the cause of my problems. Cpu temperature seems to be low enough (<40° according to a check with lm-sensors).

Comparing the outputs of the queries with this thread:
[Laptop randomly shutting down / suspending after a few minutes. 20.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1340857/laptop-randomly-shutting-down-suspending-after-a-few-minutes-20-04-2-lts)
I find a few differences:

1. journalctl is completely filled with `xxx: Failed to write 'change' to '/sys/devices/virtual/xxx/uevent': Permission denied`,
   With various xxx.
2. The kern.log file shows different messages:
   Even tough the system only shuts down after > 60 seconds, the last entry is made before between 12 and 100 seconds:
   `rfkill: input handler enabled`

**Edit:** Reading up on it more, the issue of power supply comes up sometimes. For me the problem appears running only on battery, running with cable and battery, and when using only the cable with a detached battery

**Edit 2:**
Journalctl does not contain the messages above, i don't remebember where i found them. journalctl indeed shows the line `systemd-logind[790]: Power key pressed`,
If therre a way to disable this from shutting down the laptop?

Comment: This seems to be a hardware issue. I think the issue is so severe that I don't see how Ubuntu, as an operating system could help you out in this scenario. This may be a question for superuser.com or for anyone who is more hardware-oriented...

Comment: "For me the problem appears running only on battery, running with cable and battery, and when using only the cable with a detached battery" — in other words, whatever you do power-supply-wise, this is the behaviour?

Comment: Yes, it does not seem to depend on the type of power supply

Comment: Try something: let the laptop rest and cool down, then, afterwards, try to boot straight into recovery mode. Does it act more stable in recovery mode? Can it stay on half an hour? An hour? If yes, then you could risk a disk check with `fsck`. Don't use any options that would try to change the disk in any ways. Just a read-only scan of the disk to see if there are any errors.

Comment: Even better idea: get an Ubuntu live USB and boot from that. If the issue would be somehow related to the HDD/SSD, then the live USB would operate perfectly stable, since your USB media is intact and undamaged. First of all, verify whether the system is stable. If yes, then while booted from the live USB, you could really mount your primary disk, and carry out any operation with `fsck` that seems to be necessary, including repair attempts. (But beforehand, *create a backup** of all the data on the primary disk that you wouldn't want to lose. `fsck` is good, but its success rate is not 100%)